# When CiviMRF is used with Form Processor, how can I view the results of each transaction?

Tags: form-processor

I am using CiviMFR on Drupal 7 as the public facing server and Form Processor on a Drupal 7/CiviCRM installation as the internal server. I see that when I use form processing locally on the CiviCRM installation (Try It), the results are shown on the page.

When a user submits a Webform from the public facing site and the data is sent to the CiviCRM installation, is there a way to view the results of each transaction on the Civi side? I'm interested in being able to know when a transaction has failed.

I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One can view the results of API calls within CiviCRM by using the extension [API Rest Log](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-rest-log). It contains the time, entity, action and parameters of the call. However, it does not contain the error responses for the call. But..

From the public site, one can view the result of each API call (request and response) by viewing the CiviMRF Call Log (admin/reports/civimrf_calls). This can be accessed from the Reports menu. This log shows both failed and completed requests.